# What is a good method of doing TDD with legacy Delphi code having embedded SQL

Tags: sql, delphi, testing, tdd, bdd

I have to take some legacy Delphi code pointing to a database and make it support a new, better, database having a completly different schema. The updated database has the same data. It has a combination of stored procedures and embedded SQL.

Is there a good Test driven development technique that will help make sure I don't break anything? This code has amost no unit tests and I need to make changes to a lot of hard coded SQL.

Just running after every change sounds error prone and time consuming. I love the idea of doing TDD or BDD, just not sure how to do it.

Comment: It's completely impossible for anyone to know if you will be able to get your code "under test" enough for you to use tests effectively during refactoring. My efforts to do this in giant badly structured Delphi legacy codebases have never yielded any result that was worth the time it took.  I remain sceptical. Maybe TDD works in C# and Java.

Answer (score 13):

It's good that you want to get into unit testing, but I'd like to caution you against taking it on over-zealously.

Adding unit tests to legacy code is a major undertaking, and it's almost always totally unfeasible to halt other work just to add test cases. Also, unless you already have experience in TDD, that learning curve itself can prove a troublesome hurdle to overcome.

However, if you persevere, and take things one step at a time, your efforts will be rewarded in the end.

The problems you're likely to encounter:

- Legacy applications are usually very difficult to 'retro-fit' with test cases. This is because the code wasn't written with testability in mind.

  - Many routines are doing too many things, so tests have to consider large numbers of side-effects.
  - Code is not properly self-contained, so setting up pre-conditions for a test is a lot of work.
  - Entry points for testing/checking behaviour are often missing because they weren't needed for production code; and therefore weren't added in the first place.
  - Code often relies on global state somewhere. Either directly, or via Singleton's. This global state (regardless of where it lies) plays havoc on your test cases.
- Unit testing of databases is inherently more difficult than other kinds of unit testing. The reason for this is that test cases don't like global state - and databases are effectively massive containers of global state. Problems manifest themselves in many ways:

  - If you're using IDENTITY columns, Auto Inc or number generators of any form: These either result in a specific difference between each test run, or you need a way to reset those numbers between tests.
  - Databases are slow. Once you've built up a large number of test cases it will be impractical to run all tests between every change. (One of my Db Test suites takes almost 10 minutes to run.)
  - If your database generates date/time values, these can also complicate testing. Especially if the database runs on a different machine.
  - Database testing is complicated by the fact that there are two aspects to the database: Its schema, and its data. So if you wish to test a new/changed stored procedure (part of the schema), it needs appropriate changes to the data and possibly to other aspects of the schema (such as tables/views).
- Even without the above extra complications, there are the 'normal problems' you'll have to deal with.

  - Global state often crops up unexpectedly in some awkward places. Consider `Now()` which returns a TDateTime. It uses global state: the current date-time. If you have time/date based rules in your system, those rules may return different results depending on when your tests are run. Unless you find an effective way to deal with this challenge, you'll have a number of "erratic" test cases.
  - Writing test cases is a fundamentally different programming paradigm to what most developers are used to. It can be extremely difficult to break old habits. The style of test case code is almost declarative: ***Given** this*, ***When** I do This*, ***I expect** this to have happened*. Test cases need to be simple and clear about what they're trying to achieve.
  - The learning curve can be tricky. Initially you may find yourself taking 3 times as long to write code if unfamiliar with test cases. And even though it will eventually improve (possibly even to the point where you're faster than you used to be with unstructured and haphazard testing) - other people around you will likely express frustration. (Not cool if it's your boss.)

### Hopefully I haven't discouraged you, I do have some practical advice:

As the saying goes "Don't bite off more than you can chew."
Be prepared to start out slow. For the time being, carry on with most of your work in a way that's familiar to you. *But force yourself to write 1 or 2 test cases every day*. As you get more comfortable, you can increase this number.

Try stick to the "tried and tested principles"
The TDD work flow is : **first** write the **test** and ensure the test **fails**. I know it is difficult to stick to the habit, but the principle serves a very important purpose. It's a level of confirmation that your test case **proves** the bug / missing feature.  Far too often I've seen test case code that would pass with/without the production change - making the test somewhat useless.

For your database tests you'll need to establish a framework that works for you.
First, you'll need a mechanism of getting your database to a 'base-state'. One from which all your tests should be able to pass - no matter what order or how many times they are run. Typically this will involve some sort of **Reset** between tests (but it needs to be quite quick). Second, you'll need an easy way to update the schema of your database to what is expected by production code.

Initially you'll only want to test new features, or bug fixes.
Avoid the temptation to test everything. Over time, your test case coverage will increase. Once your framework and patterns have been established, then you might get a chance to start adding tests just to increase coverage.

Refactoring existing code.
As you become familiar with testing, you'll learn about the coding habits that make testing more difficult. You'll probably find many such problems in legacy code. Such code will not be testable as is. You may need to refactor your code before you can even test it. Obviously this is not ideal, because you'd rather have tests that always pass to prove that your changes haven't broken anything. A good book on refactoring will give you some techniques you can use that will change the structure of your code without changing its behaviour.

Testing existing code.
When writing a test for an existing routine, look at the code and determine each of the inputs that can effect different behaviour. E.g. When there's an **if** statement, something will cause the condition to evaluate to True, and something else to False. At a minimum, you'll want a test for each permutation.

Answer (score 2):

In your place I would use **DUnit** to create a unit test project. For each of the entities I would write testing methods that would run the old and new sentences and then write methods to compare the results.

I would write a TTestCase class named, let´s say **TMyTestCase**, and add some helper methods to it, then would create my new test classes as subclasses from **TMyTestCase**.

The idea of the ancestor class is to provide common functionality that makes it easier to write the tests (the comparison methods, for intance) in order the enhance productivity and comfort.

Answer (score 0):

You can start building a database simulator. Connect it instead of the old one and see what it  needs to do. Lot of work though